# Shifting the view for the keyboard and then pressing home, back to view results in non shifted view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I use the code below atm. It is working fine as long as you don't quit the app (press home) while the keyboard is up. So I thought, simple, just resignFirstResponder in viewWillDissappear:(BOOL)animated, but that does not get called pressing home apparently...

So quick recap of the problem scenario:
Tap the textView -> keyboard comes up, view is shifted
Press home
Open app again -> keyboard still up, view is back where it was, so content not visible

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }

- (void) keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification*) aNotification;
    {       
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect rect = [[self view] frame];
        rect.origin.y -= 60; 
        [[self view] setFrame: rect];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    - (void) keyboardWillHide: (NSNotification*) aNotification;
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        CGRect rect = [[self view] frame];
        rect.origin.y += 60;
        [[self view] setFrame: rect];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add notification for enter background event, like the following code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Add this 
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:) 
                                                 name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object: nil];
}
```

And in the function

```
- (void) handleEnteredBackground:(NSObject*)obj
{
    //Adjust your views   
}
```